# How to turn on SSL-layer compression for .Net HttpWebRequest client?

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, compression

Apache/Perl-based HTTPS server that I'm using supports compression in SSL Layer. That means that all client-server communications are compressed, and not just server responses, as in HTTP compression.

.Net 4 client is working with this server over HTTPS using HttpWebRequest. Is it possible to enable SSL-layer compression on the client side?

Comment: There are risks associated with TLS compression. Causing most browsers disable it a few weeks ago. Only enable it if you're sure that you're not mixing trusted and untrusted data in a single connection. Check the [security.SE blog](http://security.blogoverflow.com/2012/09/how-can-you-protect-yourself-from-crime-beasts-successor) for details on the vulnerability.

Comment: @CodesInChaos There's life beyond browsers and for most TLS uses compression would be safe. People are so much focused on browsers, that don't know that browsers produce quite small share of HTTP (not talking about TLS) traffic.

Comment: @Eugene That's why I talked about mixing trusted and untrusted data, since the attack only applies in that case.